# Como puedo identificar cuando un numero se repite en un vector de N posiciones?

Tags: vectores, sl

Mi objetivo es generar un vector con valores enteros aleatorios de N posiciones y buscar si un elemento K se encuentra repetido en el vector. Entonces, cuando entrara por teclado el numero que se repite debe mostrarme una nota de 'si. Se repite' o si no se repite.

He estoy utilizando un metodo de busqueda secuencial para encontrar el valor o valeres que se repiten, pero no se como mostrar o ponerle al codigo que me muestre ese valor.

**Nota**: Lo estoy programando en **lenguaje SL** y utilizo un programa que se llama **SLE2** de CNC. Tambien puede hacerse en **PSeInt.**

```
const
    N = 27
var
    arreglo : vector[N] numerico
    i, k, iElemento : numerico
    encontrado : logico
inicio 
    cls()

    i = 1

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
        arreglo[i] = random(100)
        i = i + 1
    }

    i = 1

    desde i = 1 hasta N
    {
        imprimir (arreglo[i])
        imprimir (" ")
    }

    imprimir("\n")

    imprimir("Escriba el numero que se repite: ")
    leer(k)

    i = 1
    encontrado = FALSE
    iElemento = 0
    mientras (i <= N and not (encontrado))
    {
        si(arreglo[i] == k)
        {
         encontrado = TRUE
        }
        i = i + 1
    }

    si (encontrado)
    {
        imprimir ("\n Elemento ", k, " se encontro en el vector")
    sino
        imprimir ("\n Elemento no se repite en el vector ")
    }
fin
```

En la linea **43** que es la **condicion si**, no tiene nada como condicion. He intentado poner un valor **logico** para que se cumplan esas codiciones de ese **si**, y una variable que me de vuelva un numero sea 0 o 1 para esa condicion. Pero no se me cumple.

Comment: `si(encontrado)` o `si(encontrado==TRUE)`

Comment: Edite el codigo y de la dos forma lo he intentado asi y no me funciona. Solo se mantiene en la primera condicion si busco un numero que no se repite